# Linq never finding element in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following `XDocument` called `XDoc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <DatabaseList>
      <Database DatabaseName="c2501_data">
      <Plugin PluginName="FooPlugin" LastRun="1/21/2013 3:22:08 PM" />
      <Plugin PluginName="SpecialPlugin" LastRun="2013-01-21T15:22:09.3791103-05:00" />
      <Plugin PluginName="BarPlugin" LastRun="2013-01-21T15:23:13.0964814-05:00" />
   </Database>
</DatabaseList>
```

I'm writing a program that searches to see when the last time a plugin was run on a database, if at all. I use the following two pieces of code to figure out if an entry exists for a plugin on a database:

```
        var h = (from el in XDoc.Root.Elements("Database")
                 where el.Element("Plugin").Attribute("PluginName").Value=="FooPlugin" 
                 && el.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value=="c2501_data"
                 select el.Element("Plugin"));

        var e = (from el in XDoc.Root.Elements("Database")
                 where el.Element("Plugin").Attribute("PluginName").Value=="BarPlugin"
                 && el.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value == "c2501_data"
                 select el.Element("Plugin"));


        if ((from el in XDoc.Root.Elements("Database")
             where el.Element("Plugin").Attribute("PluginName").Value == "BarPlugin"
             && el.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value == "c2501_data"
             select el.Element("Plugin")).Count() == 0)
        {
            XElement SpecialPlugin = new XElement("Plugin",
                new XAttribute("PluginName", "BarPlugin"),
                new XAttribute("LastRun", DateTime.Now));

            var CurNode = from node in XDoc.Root.Elements("Database")
                          where (string)node.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value == "c2501_data"
                          select node;

            foreach (var node in CurNode)
                node.Add(SpecialPlugin);

            XDoc.Save(RuntimesPath);
            //XDoc.Root.Elements("Database").Attribute("DatabaseName").
        }
```

The problem that I'm having is that even though there is clearly an entry for `BarPlugin`, the count will always return 0 and `e` will always be unable to create an enumberable. Can anyone explain to me why this might be? `FooPlugin` always works correctly and returns the Plugin information for `h`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting a `Database` element where it contains a child element called `Plugin` with a given name.  Since you have only one `Database` element, you're getting the same outer element each time.  You then take that database element and return the first `Plugin` child, which will always be Foo, in this case.  You need to find the appropriate `Database` element and then query through each of the child elements so you can return them:

```
public static XElement GetPlugin(XDocument XDoc, string databaseName, string pluginName)
{
    var h = from database in XDoc.Root.Elements("Database")
            where database.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value == databaseName
            from plugin in database.Elements("Plugin")
            where plugin.Attribute("PluginName").Value == pluginName
            select plugin;

    return h.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or, if you prefer, in method syntax:

```
var q = XDoc.Root.Elements("Database")
    .Where(db => db.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value == databaseName)
    .SelectMany(db => db.Elements("Plugin"))
    .Where(plugin => plugin.Attribute("PluginName").Value == pluginName);

return q.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var db = XDoc.Root.Elements("Database");
var z = (from el in db.Elements("Plugin")
        where el.Attribute("PluginName").Value == "BarPlugin"
              && el.Parent.Attribute("DatabaseName").Value == "c2501_data"
              select el).FirstOrDefault();
if(z != null)
    .....
```

*I'm using `Elements()` method, to get all child elements and `Parent` property to look for the parent element "DatabaseName"*.

Problem in your code is that your `el.Element()` is searching only for the first element, thus it can find only "FooPlugin", which is on the first position in the xml.

From MSDN doc `Element()`:

> Gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified XName.